# How to re-enable the default themes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I don't have the default themes available anymore.

[image: themeSelection]

But I would like to be able to select the dark+ default theme.

I have searched in the Extensions panel but nothing shows up, it does not seem to be available to be re-downloaded or re-enabled.

Does anyone know how to get the default themes available again?

Comment: Search for Default Themes extension in the extension tab and check if it is enabled.

Comment: Oh yeah, was confused, but i had to search for "@builtin". And in the theme section enable again the default themes. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Dorin Botan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688984/vscode-how-to-have-default-theme-aviable-again/72692281?answertab=trending#comment128397502_72688984), I just needed to do input `@builtin` to the Extensions panel:

[image: screenshot of VS Code Extensions panel with @builtin in search field]

And then from the Setting icon, enable the default themes again.